# Why is there を coupled with potential form?

Tags: grammar, particle-を, potential-form

For full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_1130.html?utm_int=news_contents_tokushu_002

The sentence in question:
その後、適切なケアを受けられないと、「次の子どもを愛せない」など深刻なケースにつながることが分かってきました。

My attempt at translation:
We found out that afterwards, if they cant undergo appropriate care, it can severe cases where they cant love the next child.

The way I translated 適切なケアを受けられない  a が instead of an を would be needed. But maybe I just misinterpreted the whole thing, that's why IM asking here ^^

Furthermore, I couldn't really find an entry on jisho for 愛せない. All I found was this https://jisho.org/search/%E6%84%9B%E3%81%9B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84 but it leads to a dead link ^^
I just assumed that it would mean "to love" but I couldn't find confirmation anywhere, especially since I must admit that I cant really use goo jisho...^^

And finally, just on a sidenote: Why is 「次の子どもを愛せない」 put into brackets? The way I used it it's kind of a relative attribute, but it seems to be more of a quotation from an interview or the like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The potential form can use を and it is generally equivalent to using が. Ironically, you asked about this before in the similar medical context [How does the passive function in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/53608/how-does-the-passive-function-in-this-sentence). You can read more here: [The difference between が and を with the potential form of a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/609/the-difference-between-%E3%81%8C-and-%E3%82%92-with-the-potential-form-of-a-verb)

愛する + potential + negation = 愛せる + negation = 愛せない

I think the brackets are just used to more clearly indicate the type of things など is referring to. A style thing so to say.